# How to set the output frequency for the PPS pin on the CD-PA1616S GPS module? (Used in Adafruit Ultimate GPS board)

Tags: gps

The [datasheet](https://cdn-shop.adafruit.com/product-files/746/CD+PA1616S+Datasheet.v03.pdf) says you can change the freqnecy...

> 1.5 1PPS
> A pulse per second (1 PPS) is an electrical signal which precisely indicates the start of a second with the accuracy of ±20ns RMS (Root Mean Square). The PPS signal is provided through a designated output pin for many external applications. The pulse is not only limited to being active every second **but is also allowed to set up the required duration, frequency,** and active high/low through a programmable user-defined setting.

...but I can not find any info on how to.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Usually if that sort of thing isn't in the datasheet, then there's a user's manual or reference manual that does.  Because this is Adafruit, you may want to find the part number of the chip used and see if you can find the data on _that_.

Comment: @TimWescott yea, checked every datasheet and user guide and app note I could find for this board, the module, and the chipset and can not find anywhere that sets the PPS frequency. :/

Answer (score 1):

The [CD-PA1616S web page](https://www.cdtop-tech.com/products/pa1616s) says it is a drop-in replacement for the [Gtop PA6H](https://cdn-shop.adafruit.com/product-files/4279/4279_CD_PA1616S_Datasheet.pdf) module.

The PA64 datasheet is pretty much word for word the same, but also talks about customisation services, including for PPS.  A third extremely similar one  is [Mediatek MT3333](https://d86o2zu8ugzlg.cloudfront.net/mediatek-craft/documents/mt3333/MT3333_Datasheet.pdf), which also says the PPS is configurable.

There is also a Gtop [PMTK Packet User Manual](https://cdn.sparkfun.com/assets/parts/1/2/2/8/0/PMTK_Packet_User_Manual.pdf) which perhaps has the command you need: you'll have to work out for yourself whether they apply to the exact module you have.  It only appears to control the pulse width, but perhaps a different version of this command would change other things.

[image]